# Change in cats drinking behavior?

Tags: cats

My cat is a large lad, healthily weighing in at 15.1lbs that comes with an enlarged heart requiring a 1/4 of a pill of blood thinner at night + .5 pill of diuretic, and 1 pill of diuretic in the morning.

He's just turning 3ys now and loves to howl for his afternoon leash walkes around our complex.

So recently I got both my cats a new fountain. They had a Drinkwell Mini fountain (the one that looks like a toliet) and replaced with another Drinkwell, only this time it's the Multi-Tier version with an open top. We also changed food from Blue Buffalo Sensitive Stomach to Blue Buffalo. We've done a bunch of different foods, because we thought our second cat had a sensitive stomach when it turned out he just scarfs and barfs.

He's always loved drinking from our bathroom sink faucet, and will jump up and mew until we turn it on. But Whenever he approaches the new fountain, despite the open top, he'll paw and paw at the edges of the bowl before sticking his head into the side for water.
I've kept the fountain full every day, and clean it every 2-3 days by soaking it in hot water and then washing it out.
However, hes now discovered cups of water and has taken to knocking them over if he can't get the water from them.

I've owned cats before, and this is no surprise. I'm concerned that he's not liking the new water dish so much and is losing on hydration.

Comment: You say "He's always loved drinking from our bathroom sink faucet" and he's "sticking his head into the side for water." Is he drinking from the basin at the bottom, or the front where it flows down?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do when your cat changes eating or drinking behaviour is to visit the vet and get bloodwork done,this is to exclude medical problems as a cause for the changes.

Most likely your cat does not like some aspect of the water fountain,there is a couple of things you might try one is moving the fountain to a place away from the food if you have not done so already.

An other ting you might try is to put the fountain on a timer in case it is the sound your cat does not like,like let the fountain run for 1 hr and off for two hours.

You can try to change the area where the fountan is located and remove any obstructions that other pets can hide behind in case your cat feels unsafe when he is drinking.

And last you might have to change to an other type of water fountain or put up an additional waterbowl in an other room of your house.